# MPAndroidChart - how to set custom colors in PieChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Is it any way to assign colors to slices in PieChart?
For example:
PieEntry1: Green, PieEntry2: Red, PieEntry3: Blue

I know I can use method dataSet.setColor(colorList), but sometimes some values are 0, then I'm not add them to chart. Situation like this will disturb the coloring order. Or is it possible to not show values equal 0?

If for example val2 equal to 0, the color of val3 will be RED, but I want it to be BLUE.

Here is my code:

```
    List<PieEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();

    if(val1>0.0f)
        entries.add(new PieEntry(val1, "Val1"));
    if(val2>0.0f)
        entries.add(new PieEntry(val2, "Val2"));
    if(val3>0.0f)
        entries.add(new PieEntry(val3, "Val3"));

    PieDataSet set = new PieDataSet(entries, "");

    final int[] sliceColors = {Color.GREEN, Color.RED, Color.BLUE};
    ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int color : sliceColors){
        colors.add(color);
    }

    set.setColors(colors);

    PieData data = new PieData(set);
    pieChart.setData(data);
    pieChart.invalidate();
```

Comment: Why don't you add value 0. You can display it using legend like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61224920/how-to-display-labels-in-android-using-mpandroidchart-pie-chart/61228003#61228003)

Comment: because values overlap and chart is illegible

Answer (score 0):

You can use value formatter like this:

```
public class PieDataFormatter extends PercentFormatter {

    private PieChart pieChart;

    public PieDataFormatter(PieChart pieChart) {
        super(pieChart);
        this.pieChart = pieChart;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPieLabel(float value, PieEntry pieEntry) {
        if (pieChart != null && pieChart.isUsePercentValuesEnabled()) {
            // Converted to percent
            return value == 0 ? "" : getFormattedValue(value);
        } else {
            // raw value, skip percent sign
            return value == 0 ? "" :  mFormat.format(value);
        }
    }
}
```

And set value formatter. You don't need to check value 0

```
PieData data = new PieData(set);
data.setValueFormatter(new PieDataFormatter(pieChart));
pieChart.setData(data);
pieChart.invalidate();
```

If you want, you can use [legend](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61228003/8956604)